# session not being created by jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, facebook, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter 3.1.2 and trying to implement Facebook login in my app. When user logged in and authorized my app then I want to save some user info in my DB and then create session.

All working fine except creation of sessions, this is why user not being logged into my app after successfully authorize my app.

On click on FB login button following code is firing

```
FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var site_url = $('#site_url').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: site_url + 'weapons/register',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    email: response.email
                }
            });
            window.location.href = '<?php echo site_url_tr('profile'); ?>';
        }
    }, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});
```

Here is my register method

```
public function register() {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $user = array(
            'email' => $email
        );
        $u = $this->pm->total_item('users', 'email', $email);
        if ($u < 1) {//if user not exist then create
            $this->db->set('reg_date', 'NOW()', FALSE);
            $user_id = $this->pm->insert_data('users', $user, TRUE);
        }else{
            $user = $this->pm->get_row('email', $email,'users');
            $user_id = $user['id'];
        }
        $user_data = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'username' => $email,
            'email' => $email,
            'user_type' => 'user'
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
    }
```

`$this->session->set_userdata($user_data);` so this was my attemp to create session and its not working. And not redirecting to `Profile` controller from my `JS` code above. Thanks

> I have auto loaded `session` library and drivers. Any Idea how can I
>   create session (via Codeigniter) when user authorize my app most
>   welcome

Comment: Apart from the async issue - what does `site_url` contain? If that contained any value that made the request cross-domain, then cookies won't be send with the request unless you add the `withCredentials` flag.

Comment: @CBroe `site_url` here `<?php echo site_url();?>` which is `http://localhost/project_name/`

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you included `$this->load->library('session');` in your file or autoloaded it.
2. Ajax calls are asynchrone : you are redirecting before you have the chance to complete the request.

   $.ajax({
      // parameters 
   }).done(function(){ 
      // redirect here
   });

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I have already autoloaded including session library and drivers. Also redirection tried in `done` nothing happened

Comment: Usually response.status contains a code (200 for success, 404 not found..) maybe it comes from there. I think you should console.log(response) before the if variable on your client.

Comment: here is my console data of `response` is `Object {authResponse: Object, status: "connected"}`

Comment: `Type: "Post"` should be `method: "POST"` can we have any kind of feedback from the server that actually would tell us that the request did pass or not ?

Comment: Stop assuming. If you know then comment/answer. All you said is tried nothing worked